# Python program doesn't write in a file

Tags: python, file

**The user gives input to the program and it should write it in a file** There is a problem with uploading it to the txt file.

```
Plan = open("Plan.txt", "r")
content = Plan.read()
Plan_lista = content.split(",")
Przedmioty = []

Przedmioty = list(set(Plan_lista))
Przedmioty.remove("")
Plan.close()

#Dodawanie linków do listy
Linki = open("Linki.txt", "w+")

print("\n" + "Podaj Link do:")
a=0;
for i in range(len(Przedmioty)):
    print (Przedmioty[a], end = "\r")
    link = input(": ")
    Linki.write(Przedmioty[a] + "," + link)

    if ( a != len(Przedmioty)-1):
        Linki.write(", ")
    a+=1
```

Comment: You are opening you file with read only, you need to open with write as well: `Plan = open("Plan.txt", "+")`. Heres the docs for [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: @joshmeranda, it looks like they are opening the file they are writing to `Linki` with `"w+"`, so that's not the issue?

Comment: You open `Linki` for writing, but you never close it and you don't flush it either. Have you considered using `with open("Linki.txt", "w+") as Linki:` instead? That way, you can't forget to close it, it will automatically wrap things up at the end of the `with` block. Otherwise, close the file at the end of the script. If you want to see results as you're writing them, use `Linki.flush()` after each write.

Comment: @Grismar All files are closed when the script ends.

Comment: @Barmar, I suspect OP is watching the file while they are writing inputs and perhaps killing the script so it doesn't actually get flushed to disk at all. (note how they are pausing for input before every write)